# Update image in UIImageView

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I try to make UIKit element with replaceable image in it, that I can use like swiftUI element.

I stuck at the moment, when image in UIImageView should be refreshed with imageInBlackBox from ObservableObject. I try'd to set new imageInBlackBox from updateUIView and from imagePickerController after image has been selected. But both of this methods don't update UIImageView, it works only for swiftUI Image element, that I use for test.

How I should make imageView.image be refreshed after imageInBlackBox change?

[image]

```
  //Data model
      struct imageAdderDataHolder: Identifiable, Hashable {
            var id: UUID = UUID()
            var isShowingImagePicker:Bool = false
            var imageInBlackBox:UIImage = UIImage(systemName: "photo")! // image for replace
            var height: CGFloat = 160
            var width: CGFloat = 160
        }
        //Data storage
        class imageAdderData: ObservableObject{
            init() {}
            static let shared = imageAdderData()
            @Published var img1: imageAdderDataHolder = imageAdderDataHolder()
        }
        
        struct simpleadder: UIViewRepresentable{
            @ObservedObject var imageData: imageAdderData = .shared
            let mainView: UIView = UIView()
            var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
            
            func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
                imageView.image = imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox
                imageView.frame.size.width = imageData.img1.width
                imageView.frame.size.height = imageData.img1.height
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                mainView.addSubview(imageView)
                return mainView
            }
            
            func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
                imageView.image = imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox // try to replace image
            }
        }
        // swiftui view for test
        struct  photoadder: View {
            @ObservedObject var imageData: imageAdderData = .shared
            var body: some View {
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        simpleadder()
                            .frame(width: imageData.img1.width, height: imageData.img1.height)
                            .border(Color.black, width:1)
                            .sheet(isPresented: $imageData.img1.isShowingImagePicker, content: {
                                imagePickerUIView(isPresented: $imageData.img1.isShowingImagePicker)
                            })
                        Image(uiImage: imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox) // working element for test
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
                            .frame(width: imageData.img1.width, height: imageData.img1.height)
                            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                    }
                    Button("change image") {
                        imageData.img1.isShowingImagePicker = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        struct imagePickerUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
            @ObservedObject var imageData: imageAdderData = .shared
            @Binding var isPresented: Bool
            func makeUIViewController(context:
                                        UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<imagePickerUIView>) ->
            UIViewController {
                let controller = UIImagePickerController()
                controller.delegate = context.coordinator
                return controller
            }
            
            func makeCoordinator() -> imagePickerUIView.Coordinator {
                return Coordinator(parent: self)
            }
            
            class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                               UINavigationControllerDelegate {
                
                let parent: imagePickerUIView
                init(parent: imagePickerUIView) {
                    self.parent = parent
                }
                
                func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:
                                            [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                    if let selectedImageFromPicker = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
// try to replace image
                        parent.imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox = selectedImageFromPicker
                    }
                    self.parent.isPresented = false
                }
            }
            func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController:
                                            imagePickerUIView.UIViewControllerType, context:
                                                UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<imagePickerUIView>) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution - in representable all views should be created inside `makeUIView`, because struct can be (and usually does) recreated on parent update (so internal instances will be recreated as well, while made UIKit views life-cycle persisted).

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4.

[image: demo]

Fixed code:

```
struct simpleadder: UIViewRepresentable{
    @ObservedObject var imageData: imageAdderData = .shared

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let mainView: UIView = UIView()               // << create here !!
        let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()    // << create here !!
        imageView.image = imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox
        imageView.frame.size.width = imageData.img1.width
        imageView.frame.size.height = imageData.img1.height
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        mainView.addSubview(imageView)
        return mainView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // find needed view in run-time
        if let imageView = uiView.subviews.first as? UIImageView {
            imageView.image = imageData.img1.imageInBlackBox
        }
    }
}
```